# canvas.setViewport(m_iTextWidth, m_iTextWidth); It dosen't work since android 4.3,Why?Is there anyother method to replace with?

Tags: android

```
canvas.setViewport(m_iTextWidth, m_iTextWidth);
```

It dosen't work since android 4.3, why?

Is there anyother method to replace with?

[image]

Comment: `android.graphics.Canvas` does not have such method

Comment: That method apparently didn't do anything, so there's no need to look for a replacement. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-developers/opNpb3qKauE

Comment: You say right, But i did want to use it,thank you.